# Materializecss chips in Rails 4 doesn't save data to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize

I have some problem with material chips in Rails (4.2.6) app. When i add class chips-initial to my input field, i can't write any data for my field. That field is nil. I don't understand why. This field is String, but when this field as Array, i got same problem.

This is my form:

```
  = simple_form_for @exemple do |f|
.input-field
  = f.input :title

.input-field
  = f.label 'content'
  = f.text_area :content, class: "materialize-textarea"

.input-field.chips.chips.chips-initial.chipschips-placeholder
      = f.input :tags

= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

this is .js for initial chips

```
 $( document ).ready(function(){
   $('.chips-initial').material_chip({
    data: [{
      tag: 'Apple',
    }, {
      tag: 'Microsoft',
    }, {
      tag: 'Google',
    }],
    placeholder: 'Enter a tag',
    secondaryPlaceholder: '+Tag',
  }
  )
});
```

in html:

```
<div class="input-field chips chips chips-initial chipschips-placeholder" data-index="0" data-initialized="true">
<div class="chip">Apple<i class="material-icons close">close</i></div>
<div class="chip">Microsoft<i class="material-icons close">close</i></div>
<div class="chip">Google<i class="material-icons close">close</i></div>
<input id="9c3fa6b9-b134-626b-ddbb-a0a12a538eed" class="input" placeholder="Enter a tag"></div>
<input id="9c3fa6b9-b134-626b-ddbb-a0a12a538eed" class="input" placeholder="Enter a tag">
```

But when i create, in console:

```
#<Example id: 3, title: "", content: "", tags: nil, place: "", date: nil, created_at: "2016-11-04 18:31:50", updated_at: "2016-11-04 18:31:50", image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil
```

I am using gem 'materialize-sass'

Comment: Came across this issue today, did you ever find a solution?